# R: Assign Variable Names based on a matrix's columns

Tags: r

I am a (very) new user to R, and trying to replicate my MATLAB codes here (prefer R to Octave at this stage).

I have the following matrix `df`:

```
variable value
th   100
tw   100
gap  30
```

I'd like to be able to assign variables, based on the first column, to the values in the second.  So basically, `th = 100`, `tw = 100`, `gap = 30`.

My end aim is to be able to manipulate the data in the following manner:

```
difference <- th-gap
```

EDIT:

```
>dput(df)
structure(list(s = structure(1:3, .Label = c("aa", "bb", "cc" ), class = "factor"),
n = c(2, 3, 5)), .Names = c("s", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Vectorize(assign, c("x", "value"))(as.character(M[,1]), M[,2], envir=globalenv())
```

where `M` is your matrix or dataframe. Note that `as.character` makes sure that factors are converted to strings before assignment.

If `M` is a character matrix containing numbers in the second column, then you might use `as.numeric(M[,2])` instead of `M[,2]`.

BUT, honestly, this is not the best approach. Using `assign` is usually frowned upon, because it's unintuitive and leads to less readable code.

You could create a list:

```
L <- as.list(M[,2])
names(L) <- M[,1]
```

and then access your data by name as in `L[["th"]]`.

Comment: Thanks. Will post the required information when I'm at my machine which runs R. However, can you explain why using assign is frowned upon? I also though of using a loop, but in my search for a solution, i read that a loop is also poor coding in R. 

I'd really like to understand why and what the thinking is behind this.

Comment: dput(df)
structure(list(s = structure(1:3, .Label = c("aa", "bb", "cc"
), class = "factor"), n = c(2, 3, 5)), .Names = c("s", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @irshaadv, I took the liberty to add this to your original post. As I said, it's "frowned upon" because it's unintuitive and leads to less readable code, in most cases. If you post what you're trying to achieve, we can help you to get more efficient/elegant way to code it in R. This question looks like a very tiny bit of a more complex task. Consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a`data.frame` which is a different object entirely to a `matrix`. A `matrix` is an atomic vector with dimension attributes that wrap it up into a `matrix`. As it is really just an atomic vector a matrix can only contain data of a single type, so you cannot have `character` data mixed with `numeric` data. A `data.frame` on the other hand is a type of list, where each list element is an atomic vector of the same length (the length gives the number of rows, the number of elements in the list is the number of columns). Each `list` element can hold data of a different type.

So lets assume you have a `data.frame`...

```
#  Construct the data
df <- read.table( text = "variable value
th   100
tw   100
gap  30" , h = TRUE )

df
#  variable value
#1       th   100
#2       tw   100
#3      gap    30

#  Subset the data.frame to the values you want using the `[` operator
difference <- df[ df$variable == 'th' , 'value' ] - df[ df$variable == 'gap' , 'value' ]
#[1] 70
```

We can subset a `data.frame` using the `[` operator. The first argument inside `[,]` refers to rows and the second argument to columns. So `[ df$variable == 'th' , 'value' ]`  returns a logical vector in the rows argument that is `TRUE` when `variable == 'th'` and returns all rows that meet this condition for the column called `value`.

Comment: Most certainly is data frame - I'm reading it in from a .csv (prepared in Excel). My challenge is that the variables change, so would prefer to have code that doesn't make explicit mention of the names of the variables. 

Additionally, I would prefer avoiding such lengthy description of the "equation" (e.g th-gap), if at all possible.